# upload multipart file springboot mockMvc Required request part 'file' is not present, testing controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, mockmvc

Getting this 'file' not present error when trying to test uploading a file, controller works fine outside testing though. Is there a reason the file isn't present here?

controller

```
public UploadResponse uploadFile(
    @RequestPart
         MultipartFile file,
     @RequestParam(value = “name”)
         String name) {}
```

test for controller

```
MockMultipartFile file
    = new MockMultipartFile(
    "photo.jpeg",
    "photo.jpeg",
    MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE,
    "photo".getBytes()
);


this.mockMvc.perform(
            multipart(“/uploadfile”)
                .file(file)
                .param(“name”, “bob”))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the file should be "file" here

```
MockMultipartFile file
    = new MockMultipartFile(
    "file",
    "photo.jpeg",
    MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE,
    "photo".getBytes()
);
```

Comment: Thank a lot for the answer. It worked after spending lot of time.